# How to integrate Bacnet into arduino

Tags: arduino, bacnet

I am trying to integrate bacnet protocol into arduino uno.I tried to add the libraries here https://github.com/bacnet-stack/bacnet-stack/tree/master/ports/arduino_uno. I tried compiling with programs like minGW WinAVR eclipse, but I kept getting errors.How can I write a code for bacnet ip with udp/ip. and finally how can i integrate bacnet protocol into arduino uno. I would be very grateful if you could help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Were you ever able to get BACnet running on Arduino?